# ThisBinding in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm pretty confused on how React Native invokes new components. For example, if I create a custom component, it doesn't seem like React creates a new instance of it. Can someone please clarify this for me? Here's some more information on my confusion:

Let's say I have some component called LoginScreen:

```
export default function LoginScreen() {
  this.email = ''
  this.password = ''

  login = async () => {
    console.log(this == global) //true
  }
...
```

If I call login when some event is triggered, a button press for example, `true` will be outputted to the console. To further examine this, I created another component in a different module:

```
function Test(){
   [text, setText] = React.useState(email)

   return (
      <View style={{height: 100}}>
      <Button onPress={() => setText(email)} title='refresh'></Button>
      <Text style={{height: 100}}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
      )
}
```

So let's say I have two login screens. `email` will be set to whichever one I update most recently. Therefore, when I press the refresh button, the text displayed will be the most recent value of `email`. This also means if I update my email and password in one login screen and then hit the login button on the other, I'll be logged in on the second login screen.

See:

[image: Two login forms]

It doesn't seem like this should be expected behavior, but if it is can someone explain to me why? I'm very new to React Native so please let me know if I've left out any details or if anything needs to be clarified.

Thank you!

Comment: Why use `this.email = "whatever"` anyway?  That's what the `useState` hook is for or, if you need some global storage container, a [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) and `<Provider/>`.

Comment: @zero298 Using `var email` would achieve my purpose as well. I don't call `useState` because whenever the text input changes I want to update email without triggering a re-render (i.e. without using something like `setEmail(<value>)`). Regardless, I'm still confused on the behavior described in the post.

Comment: Using `var email` actually solves the problem. I believe because a new lexical environment is created each time `LoginScreen` is called. I'm still confused as to why there are no instances

Comment: Can you show the structure of this?  Are `Test`s children of `LoginScreen`?  I don't see how you are able to use `this`.  Like how is `Test` able to use `email` so freely without error?  Ideally, if you want something that won't necessarily trigger a re-render you would use `useRef`.

Comment: Test is able to use `email` because `email` belongs to the global object. My question is why does it belong to global? Shouldn't it be tied to an instance of the component? Or are React components not invoked via `new` when I write: `<LoginScreen/>`, for example.

Comment: Check out the react docs on rendering a component which walks through an example of a function component: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component
For pure function components React doesn't call `new LoginScreen()`, it just calls `LoginScreen(props)` and uses the returned result - there's no instantiation, just function calls, hence "function component"

Answer (score 0):

For mutable state that you don't want to trigger a re-render, you usually use `useRef`.  These are state containers for each instance of the component that you can access and use.

Consider the following example.  Each `<Login/>` has an email and name state.  However, only the email will cause "render" to show up in console.  If you submit though, you'll see that the stat has changed for each and that it is local to each instance.  Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```js
const {
  createElement: e,
  useState,
  useRef
} = React;

function Login() {
  const nameRef = useRef("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  
  console.log("render");
  
  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(`name: ${nameRef.current} | email: ${email}`);
  }
  
  const emailChange = e => setEmail(e.target.value);
  const nameChange = e => nameRef.current = e.target.value;
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Form</legend>
        <label>
          <span>Email</span>
          <input type="text" onChange={emailChange} value={email} />
        </label>
        <label>
          <span>Name</span>
          <input type="text" onChange={nameChange} value={name.current} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  );
};

const Page = () => (
  <div>
    <Login />
    <Login />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on `useRef`. Just to be clear, I'm able to accomplish what I want. I just can't figure out why variables prefixed with `this.` belong to the global object. My thinking is that because components aren't instantiated and rather called via the global object. I'm really not sure however.